# origin/<branch_name> vs. gitlab/<branch_name>

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm pretty new to working with git and I've been working on a project on GitLab. I created a branch but I decided to change the name so I tried: `git push origin -u <new_name>`

This gave me this error: `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository`

So I looked and found that you should do this `git remote add origin`. So I added the origin and was able to push the branch I renamed. I then did `git push origin --delete <old_name>` and `git fetch --prune` to remove the old branch from the remote repository and from the references on my local repository. But now I have these branches:

```
  Connections_nonblocking
* master
  remotes/gitlab/Connections_nonblocking    
  remotes/gitlab/master    
  remotes/origin/Connections_nonblocking
```

Is there a way to remove the duplicates? Should I be working on /gitlab or /origin paths?

Comment: A remote is just a convenient label for a remote repository. It looks like you already had a remote named `gitlab`, but you've created one named `origin` pointing at the same place (you can verify that by running `git remote -v`). Assuming they're identical, you can delete either one and use whichever remains.

Comment: Ok, I just removed the one named `origin` and changed the local branch to point to `gitlab`. It looks like that cleared everything up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I created a branch but I decided to change the name

If you created your branch locally, then you need to use [`git branch -m`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--m), to move/rename your local branch.

```
git branch -m oldName newName
```

Adding a remote `origin` is a separate issue, which allows you to push said local branch.